# Creating a custom WP query for a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, query, search

I'm trying to create a WP query to search a Custom post type by its title. By using the following code, I get all portfolio posts:

```
$search_query = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
```

If I add the 's' parameter to the query (`$search_query['s'] = $keyword;`), it ignores the 'post_type' and returns blog posts instead of portfolio posts.

Comment: Check your Theme / Plugins for a `pre_get_posts` hook that modifies the post type if `is_search()` is true.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem.